# How to split string with numbers, letters and white spaces in python ?

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I want to split a string with number, letters and specific white spaces into specific components.

consider the string

```
ATLANTYS2_I          -           3103 aRNH_profile         -            121   2.7e-35  118.7   0.0   1   1   2.7e-37   5.6e-35  117.7   0.0     2   120  1342  1458  1341  1459 0.98 Gypsy      Arabidopsis thaliana_+1
```

now let the string be `content[3]`. I ran the command the

```
import re 
result = re.split(r'\s{2,}', content[3])
```

which gave me

```
['ATLANTYS2_I',
 '-',
 '3103 aRNH_profile',
 '-',
 '121',
 '2.7e-35',
 '118.7',
 '0.0',
 '1',
 '1',
 '2.7e-37',
 '5.6e-35',
 '117.7',
 '0.0',
 '2',
 '120',
 '1342',
 '1458',
 '1341',
 '1459 0.98 Gypsy\tArabidopsis thaliana_+1']
```

I have split the string by 2 spaces. but the last entry `1459 0.98 Gypsy\tArabidopsis thaliana_+1` is still grouped as one. 
I thought of splitting the last entry by one space, deleting the last entry in the result and adding the split by one space. However this seems to me rather clunky.

Is there a way to split this elegantly so that I would get the following result for the last entry 
 `'1459','0.98', Gypsy\tArabidopsis thaliana_+1'`?

Comment: I think you need to split the last entry separately even if it means more code. Better write explicit code than an "elegant" one liner that you won't understand in a month.

Comment: I agree how would you split the last entry so that I would get the desired result?

Comment: Thats a string you have defined and you cannot access by list. Refer this link for better understanding : https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use an alternation:

```
\s{2,}|\t+
# either two+ whitespaces
# or at least one tabulator space
```

---

In `Python`:

```
import re

string = "ATLANTYS2_I          -           3103 aRNH_profile         -            121   2.7e-35  118.7   0.0   1   1   2.7e-37   5.6e-35  117.7   0.0     2   120  1342  1458  1341  1459 0.98 Gypsy    Arabidopsis thaliana_+1"

rx = re.compile(r'\s{2,}|\t+')
print(rx.split(string))
```

Which yields

```
['ATLANTYS2_I', '-', '3103 aRNH_profile', '-', '121', '2.7e-35', '118.7', '0.0', '1', '1', '2.7e-37', '5.6e-35', '117.7', '0.0', '2', '120', '1342', '1458', '1341', '1459 0.98 Gypsy', 'Arabidopsis thaliana_+1']
```

Comment: `'1459 0.98 Gypsy'` must be `'1459'`, `'0.98'`, `'Gypsy'`

Answer (score 0):

You can process the last element separately:

```
last_element = result.pop()  # remove last element from list
numbers, plant = last_element.split('\t')  # split on tab
result += numbers.split()  # split the first part on spaces and add it back
result.append(plant)  # add the second part back
```

Or you could probably use a regex to split that last element correctly